# NLTK FreqDist incomplete dictionary

Tags: python, nltk

I have a problem with the following script because I'm not able to get the full list of items for each line. What I get is something like FreqDist({'be#v': 3, 'have#v': 2, 'get#v': 2, 'publicly#r': 1, 'communicate#v': 1, 'goal#n': 1, 'end#n': 1, 'delight#v': 1, 'prescription#n': 1, 'fertilize#v': 1, ...}), FreqDist({'be#v': 2, 'have#v': 2, 'get#v': 2, '20s#n': 1, 'like#v': 1, 'school#n': 1, 'think#v': 1, 'i#n': 1, 'go#v': 1, 'community#n': 1, ...}), not every word with occurrence 1 is reported.

```
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\s+', gaps=True)
m = [FreqDist(tokenizer.tokenize(line)) for line in open('1_tagged_copy.txt')]
print m
```

Solution: m = [FreqDist(tokenizer.tokenize(line)).items() for line in open('1_tagged_copy.txt')]

Comment: Can you provide a full or partial copy of `1_tagged_copy.txt` and an example of a word with occurrence 1 that isn't reported?

Comment: here you are, a line it's line this: black#a woman#n steal#v dung#n be#v consider#v student#n i#n put#v possible#a conclusion#n be#v only#r lot#n point#n womens#n issue#n way#n be#v find#v dime#n ok#v work#v major#a general#a word#n education#n erode#v neighbor#n position#n

Comment: basically words which occur one time are too much but I don't know how to extend the length of dictionary